# How do you use --no-edit by default when amending a commit in git

Tags: git

Is there somewhere in the git config file where I can make --no-edit be the default when I'm amending a commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not via a config option.

You could create an alias to accomplish the same though.

```
[alias]
        amend = "commit --amend --no-edit"
```